# check if there are any files in a directory, and if there are call another script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to write a batch script that will check if there are any files in a directory, and if there are call another script. Here is what I have :

```
@echo off

for /f %%A in ('dir /b "..\data\partials\processing"^| find /v /c ""') do set cnt=%%A


if %cnt% gtr 0 
(
    call otherscript.bat
)
```

Every time I run it I get (and a million permutations I have tried)

"The syntax of the command is incorrect."

but when I run the same command at the prompt dir /b ..\data\partials\processing | find /v /c "" it works without issue.

I'm more familiar with Bash than Batch... can someone please help?

PS> Please don't suggest powershell, it's not an option. I'm modifying an existing script.

```
@echo off
call %~dp0..\config\script\set_environment.bat
copy %ENDECA_PROJECT_DIR%\test_data\partial\* %ENDECA_PROJECT_DIR%\data\partials\incoming
for /F %%i in ('dir /b "..\data\partials\processing\*.txt"') do ( call call %~dp0runcommand.bat --skip-definition PartialUpdate 2>&1 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a matter of fact, your `if` command does have incorrect syntax. The opening bracket should go on the same line as `if`.

However, if you are counting the files only to check if the result is greater than 0, you could try a different approach:

```
(DIR /B "path" | FINDSTR . 1>NUL) && (
  command to run if the directory has files
) || (
  command to run if no file exists
)
```

The `&&` causes the following command or block of commands to run if the previous one terminated with a zero exit code. The `||` is similar but checks if the previous command or block of commands ended with a *non*-zero exit code.

The `FINDSTR` command sets a non-zero exit code if it didn't find anything in the input stream. As the search term is simply `.`, which stands for *any character*, a non-zero exit code can only be set if `DIR` resulted in an empty output, which in turn would mean the *`path`* didn't have any files.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks Andriy! I have a few strands of hair left :)

Comment: I just used this and it works great, thank you. I used (DIR /A-D /B "path" which looks for files whilst ignoring subdirectories.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I Haven't had a chance to check, just about to leave work, very similar to what you've got with a few minor changes.

```
@echo off

for /F %%i in ('dir /b "c:\mydirectory\*.*"') do (
    call otherscript.bat
    goto :EOF
)

echo Folder is empty or does not exist
```

Comment: It's still not working but probably because I have altered it in the wrong way... here is what I have for my final script -- (I modified the post above.)

Answer (score 0):

a non-empty directory will not set cnt to a filename, therefore if cnt is empty the folder is empty.

```
set cnt=
for  %%a in (..\data\partials\processing\*.*) do set cnt=%%a

if !%cnt%!==!! call otherscript.bat
```